Unable to add delay/batching to records being processed from Changestream in Apache Beam Dataflow
We have an Apache Beam (Streaming) job which is getting records from a Changestream. We read change streams using,
Step 1.
PCollection inputChangeStreams = pipeline.apply("readChangeStream1",SpannerIO.readChangeStream()
.withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)                   
.withChangeStreamName(options.getLoansDecisionResponseChangeStream())                   
.withMetadataInstance(options.getInputInstanceId())                   
.withMetadataDatabase(options.getMetaDataDatabaseId())                   
.withInclusiveStartAt(Timestamp.now()));     
return inputChangeStreams;  

Step 2.
PCollection> crdRqsIds = inputChangeStreams.apply("Extract Ids from the Changestreams", ParDo.of(new ParseChangestreamData())); 

how can we have delay in between the Step 1 and Step 2.
tried this code but didn't work -
inputChangeStreams.apply(

             "Apply Fixed Length Windows",

             Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))

                     .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())

                     .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(30))

                     .discardingFiredPanes());


I'm not 100% sure I understand the question (more detail on what you're tyring to accomplish would be helpful), but you may find Beam's state & timers constructs useful here - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers
With state, you can buffer some amount of elements or state from your changestream until you are ready to process it.
With timers, you can control when your ParDo runs (e.g. "wait 30 seconds after I see an element" or "wait 30 seconds after the close of the window").
